# How to issue query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need create query in Laravel for chart.

I need create this json file:

For example: (30 days ago)

```
[{
            "day": "23",
            "count": 20
        }, {
            "day": "22",
            "visits": 10
        }, {
            "day": "21",
            "visits": 12
        }, {
            "day": "20",
            "visits": 30
        }, {
            "day": "19",
            "visits": 20
        }, {
            "day": "18",
            "visits": 10
        }, 
         .
         .
         .
         .
        }, {
            "day": "22",
            "visits": 10
        }]
```

My code in Laravel is:

```
 $date = Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
 $ordersChart = Order::selectRaw('dayname(created_at) day, count(*) count')
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->groupBy('day')
        ->latest()
        ->get();
```

But after return `$ordersChart` show this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'laravel.orders.created_at' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select dayname(created_at) day, count(*) count from `orders` where `created_at` >= 2018-03-20 00:00:00 group by `day` order by `created_at` desc)
```

How to issue this problem?

Comment: Turn strict mode to false in your config/database.php file's mysql block and then try your query

Comment: `latest()` means `orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')` you might have multiple updated at per group which makes orderBy make no real sense

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `->latest('day')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

1- `dayname(created_at)` => `day(created_at)`

2- `latest()` => `latest('day')`

```
$ordersChart = Order::selectRaw('day(created_at) day, count(*) count')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
    ->groupBy('day')
    ->latest('day')
    ->get();
```